# is normal keep value when tomcat restart after JSESSIONID was create

Tags: java, session, tomcat

Environment
- openjdk 1.7
- tomcat 7.0.55 with native connector
- apache 2.4.10 with mod-jk 1.2.40

1. Tomcat start
2. Client request -> JSESSIONID is null
3. tomcat response -> JSESSIONID=C5EBF0AA96ADB34E0C28E4D9D2595D98 is create
4. refresh page -> session attribute(name=count, value=count++) is correct. count is increasing.
5. Tomcat stop -> start (restart) context setting is  session is not persist
6. Client refresh -> client request is send JSESSIONID=C5EBF0AA96ADB34E0C28E4D9D2595D98
7. session attribute(name=count, value=0) is reset. but keeping JSESSIONID

question.
why tomcat using JSESSIONID set by client request value? is not regenerate?

is this java spec?

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that Tomcat is giving the JSESSIONID after step 6 and that is not simply the JSESSIONID that was stored in the client's cookie? Try to delete all cookies before executing step 6 and see if you still have this behavior.

Comment: If I clear the cookies or re-run browser, of course client sends no JSESSIONID. but I keep the browser page even if tomcat restart, browser send JSESSIONID when page refresh.
And tomcat finding server session, but that sessionid is not exists. 
so I think tomcat will generate new sessionid, and response to client but don't work this. tomcat using same sessionid value of client request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is in Java spec, I would think of it as of some kind of optimization: re-using session id in general reduces number of generated ids and though possible collisions.

However tomcat will do that only for sesionids stored in cookies (for security purposes
See http://java.dzone.com/tips/turning-session-fixation for details).

To actually locate a place where tomcat 7 does this see:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.55/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java#2942

Comment: Thanks. I've found the cause.

If set sessionCookiePath="/" then tomcat create new session by requested sessionid value.

thx a lot!!